# {{product.post-summary}} оказалось ng-binding $0, а остальные корректно поаказывают Angular

Tags: json, angularjs

Хочу чтобы один из существующих product.post-summary выглядит - **Hello, World!**

**main.html**

```
<div class="hero" ng-controller="MainCtrl as store"> 
  <div class="half-item" ng-repeat="product in store.products | limitTo: 4 : 8">
    <p>{{product.post-summary}}</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

**articles.json**

```
[
{
 "name": "US Election Rundown October 4th 2016: Pre-VP Debate",
 "author": "Daniel Berman",
 "category": "US Election 2016 Rundown",
 "main-image": "../images/articles/trump-&-clinton.jpg",
 "date-created": 1475539200
}, {
 "name": "US Election Rundown September 30th 2016",
 "author": "Daniel Berman",
 "category": "US Election 2016 Rundown",
 "main-image": "../images/articles/trump-&-clinton.jpg",
 "date-created": 1475193600
}, {
 "name": "US Election Rundown September 28th 2016",
 "author": "Daniel Berman",
 "category": "US Election 2016 Rundown",
 "post-summary": "Hello, World!",
 "main-image": "../images/articles/trump-&-clinton.jpg",
 "date-created": 1475020800
}, {
 "name": "October 26 US Election 2016 Rundown",
 "author": "Daniel Berman",
 "category": " US Election 2016 Rundown",
 "main-image": "../images/articles/trump-clinton.jpg",
 "date-created": 1477440000
}
]
```

**main.js (AngularJS)**

```
angular.module('ngRestlessApp')
  .controller('MainCtrl',['$http', function ($http) {
    var store = this;
    store.products = [ ];
    $http.get('scripts/articles/articles.json').success(function(data){
      store.products = data;
    });
}]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Уже решил в тем что слова по каждому букву должна быть маленьким , а не Большие или еще без любого знака .

**post-summary** - это не слово а елемент потому что JS специально найдет слово в котором есть знак и большие буквы (например: **postSummary**), и принимает запрос.

Поэтому позволяет порядочно составить: 
**postsummary** - это верно!